# Symfony 4 isClicked method not found

Tags: php, symfony

I was trying to create a simple form and I need to check if the submit button was clicked. I checked the Symfony documentation and it tells to use "isClicked()" method. I tried to use it but the method is not found in my project.

I tried including Symfony\Component\Form\ClickableInterface and changing the button type.

```
public function play(WordRepository $rep, Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add("submit",SubmitType::class)->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $form->get("submit")->isClicked();

    return $this->render(
        "review.html.twig"
    );
}
```

Do I need to add something with Composer or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which  version using of symfony?

Comment: I'm using Symfony 4.2

Comment: How are you pressing any type of button if you are not sending the form to the view? return $this->render("review.html.twig" );, Where is the form?

Comment: paste your "review.html.twig" please. Are you hardcoding the form?

Comment: And try to use isClicked() method under the if ($form->isSubmitted())

Comment: In the question, I've pasted just an example. Actually, I pass the form as a parameter to review.html.twig. isClicked() doesn't work under if($form->isSubmitted()) either.
Here's my twig:
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}

Comment: `$form->getClickedButton()` might help

Comment: Add your form type to your question. Did you add any `SubmitType` to your form? Have you read Symfony doc? Your answer is in there... https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/multiple_buttons.html

Answer (score 7):

So your IDE is doing the complaining?  Saying that isClicked does not exist?  But the code itself works fine?

Just need to do some type casting.  The IDE knows the $form->get will return a FormInterface.  But, somewhat sadly, FormInterface does not have an isClicked method.  You need to tell the IDE that you expect a clickable object to be returned.

```
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    /** @var ClickableInterface $button  */
    $button = $form->get("submit");
    $button->isClicked();
```

Kind of strange that this never came up before.  Maybe there was was a slight code tweak someplace.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
    if ($form->isSubmitted() ) {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I can. But I kind of need more than one submit button. I'm trying to recreate a simple quiz page I once made in plain PHP and I need 4 submit buttons and check if the clicked on contained the right answer.

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does calling `isSubmitted()` resolve the given problem?